# Android, Is it possible to set list to be scroll-able horizontally?

Tags: android, list, horizontal-scrolling, inflate

In my project i have a list. this list includes thumbnail images which should be scrollable horizontally.

If i add a list inside `HorizontalScrollView` and inflate my list what will be output? I want to arrange all images horizontally.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go with [`Gallery`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) widget.

using `Gallery` would be easy for you as it is also implemented using Adapter pattern. So what you need to do is to provide Adapter implementation as you simply do for `ListView` as single image thumbnail.

or you can have a look at [`HorizontalListview`](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)